# Filter on multiple columns/fields

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have an Excel sheet which has around 10 columns and hundreds of rows. I want to apply filter on multiple columns in such a way that data is shown only when conditions on both the columns are satisfied.

One column has `Team name` and another column has `Team number`. The data should be shown only when `Team name` is either **"Projects"** or the value in the **wkFilterTeam** variable and `Team number` is **"Team2"**.

```
Function ProcessTeams(inTeamName As String) As Integer
     wkFilterTeam = inTeamName
     If (InStr(wkFilterTeam, "Markets") > 0) Then
         With Sheets("RawData")
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            Range("$A:$BG").AutoFilter
            Range("$A:$BG").AutoFilter FIELD:=3, 
            Criteria1:=Array(wkFilterTeam, "Projects"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Range("$A:$BG").AutoFilter FIELD:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Team2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
         End With
     EndIf
End Function
```

But this shows all the teams having name **Projects** and having team number as **Team2**

Comment: (a) What is `wkFilterTeam`?  (b) What is the difference between "The data should be shown only when Team name is Projects and Team number is Team2." and "this shows all the teams having name Projects and having team number as Team2"?

Comment: @YowE3K Its a variable name containing some value..

Comment: Remove it, and your code should work.

Comment: Updated my question... The Team name should be either value in wkFilterTeam or "projects" but team number must be Team2...

Comment: Given the latest change to the question, please include enough code so that we can see how `wkFilterTeam` was created and how it was assigned a value.

Comment: make sure that the field numbers are correctly assigned. Make sure `Field:=4` is indeed the Team Number column.

Comment: @YowE3K Here you go... Added some code

Comment: Please include enough code so that we can see how wkFilterTeam was created and how it was assigned a value, not just where it is being used.

Comment: @Peh Yes the columns are correct. I just want AND condtion i.e. when both conditions should satisfy but this code is behaving like OR condition, data is displayed when either of these 2 condition is true.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the incorrectly filtered data, i.e. showing where column D does not contain "Team2" for instance.

Comment: Do you mean filtering for `wkFilterTeam AND "Projects" AND "Team2"`? Because your filter should filter for `(wkFilterTeam OR "Projects") AND "Team2"` now. The first one should not be possible because Field 3 can not be `wkFilterTeam` and `"Projects"` at the same time.

Comment: `(Field3=wkFilterTeam OR Field3= "Projects") AND Field4="Team2"` This is what my requirement is but its working like `(Field3= wkFilterTeam OR Field3= "Projects" OR Field4="Team2"`

Comment: Given that `wkFilterTeam` is a `String` variable, which must include the string `"Markets"` within it, there is no reason why your code will be doing a filter which has an "OR" between field3 and field4 - AutoFilter doesn't allow `Or` conditions across fields even though many people would like to be able to do so.  Please post a screenshot of the data after it has been incorrectly filtered, i.e. showing where column D does not contain "Team2" for instance.

Comment: @YowE3K Column D does contain "Team2" but it should only shown when value in column C for corresponding row is either "Projects" or wkFilterTeam. I hope I am not confusing you...

Comment: @SachinMhetre but that's exactly what your code does. Can you add a screenshot of the data before filtering and a screenshot of the faulty filtered result? And please tell use the value of wkFilterTeam (you can print it to the debug window with `debug.print wkFilterTeam`.

Comment: So none of the after-filter rows show anything other than "Team2" in column D.  What values are showing in column C that you believe shouldn't be shown?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add `Criteria2` and switch to the `xlOr` operator?

Comment: @Vegard why should he do? What he wants is AND not OR: "I just want AND condtion".

Comment: I interpret his problem as needing an OR between the conditions in field 3, and an AND between field 3 and field 4. He states this in an earlier comment, quote: "`(Field3=wkFilterTeam OR Field3= "Projects") AND Field4="Team2"`". So my question is, why use `xlFilterValue` in `Field3`? Is there a reason adding `Criteria2` and switching to `xlOr` wouldn't work?

Comment: @Vegard I see no difference between using `Criteria1:=Array("a", "b")` and using `Criteria1:="a", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="b"`. Both end up with `a` *or* `b` due to my tests, don't they?

Comment: I agree on the theory, but OP is claiming they can't get it to work - I am not disagreeing with your solution, just suggesting an alternative for OP if they cannot get yours to work.

Comment: Hi All, the issue has been resolved. The actual issue was '.' missing before `Range`. Without '.', the `Range` was applied on active sheet and not on the specified sheet. Thanks everyone for all your help..

Comment: @SachinMhetre oh man, too bad no one has seen that because we should have.